# Java development using INTEL SDK

Tags: java, intel, perceptual-sdk

I am beginner for app development using Intel SDK. I want to start a development on java, I have downloaded intel sdk and ran the small demo application.It works fine. In order to start the java hello world program, I ran small java program on eclipse but its not supporting.

Can you guys share me any tutorials links for Java development using  Intel® Perceptual Computing SDK 2013?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the SDK you mean?  Is it even a Java SDK?

Comment: @PeterLawrey  http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/04/05/introducing-the-intel-perceptual-computing-sdk-2013. Its not a java sdk.

Comment: Given it is a new C/C++ library, it is quite likely no-one has used it in Java or posted anything on it.  You could be the first.

Comment: I suggest you contact the author as he may be aware of any such tutorials.  If he doesn't know, I suspect you need to write your own.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Intel has create a JNI for the Perceptual Computing SDK

Answer (score 0):

There is a java tutorial out on the [Perceptual Computing Download Site](https://software.intel.com/en-us/vcsource/tools/perceptual-computing-sdk). This tutorial is in the [SDK Documentation](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/perceptual_computing/documentation/html/index.html?devguide_portability_and_interoperability_guidelines.html) - look under "SDK Tutorials" and "My First Java Application"

You will need to install JDK 1.7.0_11 or later. Set the environment variable JAVA_HOME to point to the installation directory for easy reference.

1.Create a directory called Java1.
2.Launch any editor and enter the Java code Java1.java.

```
import intel.pcsdk.*;
import java.lang.System.*;

public class Java1 {


public static void main(String s[]) {
   PXCUPipeline pp=new PXCUPipeline();
   if (!pp.Init(PXCUPipeline.GESTURE)) {
       System.out.print("Failed to initialize PXCUPipeline\n");
       System.exit(3);
   }
   for (;;) {
       if (!pp.AcquireFrame(true)) break;
       PXCMGesture.GeoNode[] nodes=new PXCMGesture.GeoNode[5];
       if (pp.QueryGeoNode(PXCMGesture.GeoNode.LABEL_BODY_HAND_PRIMARY,nodes))
           System.out.print("GeoNode primary-palm ("+nodes[0].positionImage.x+","+nodes[0].positionImage.y+")\n");
       pp.ReleaseFrame();
   }
   pp.Close();
   System.exit(0);
   }
}
```

3.Build and run the Java application:

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac" -classpath PXCUPipeline.jar *.java
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java"  -classpath PXCUPipeline.jar;. Java1
```

The Java application prints out palm position if detected.